# symfony + knp_snappy : gtk-WARNING cannot open display

Tags: symfony, gtk, pdf-generation

In a symfony application, i'm using knp_snappy to generate PDF :

```
return new Response(
         $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutput($url),
         200,
         array(
                 'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
                )
        );
```

but i recieve this error :

```
The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)java version "1.7.0_79"

[more here ... cut for clarity]

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

(wkhtmltopdf:12934): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
"
stdout: ""
command: wkhtmltopdf --lowquality 'http://symfony.dev/app_dev.php/application/reporter/674/inventory' '/tmp/knp_snappy5643248854b563.21161953.pdf'.
```

Please note that :

- the given `$url` does work and is an absolute URL (as it contains link to CSS).
- if i use
  `$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html)` instead of `$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutput($url)`
  it all work fine, but then i can't load the css (and that's the normal behaviour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point was that the requested URL was behind a firewall, so wkhtmltopdf was recieving a 302 access denied.

For knp_snappy users facing the same problem, the solution  is really well explained [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/44) and [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/42).

Hope that helps!